# Signin with Login requires Button to click twice to open Google Login Page | Expo | Expo Auth Session

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I have setup a login with google functionality in React Native App. The Login Button works and login works too, however the Login Button needs to be clicked twice to open "Sign In with Google" popup.

The function that handles login is available in my custom authentication hook and is called in of the child components named Login.

Authenication Hook:

```
const SignInWithGoogle = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    promptAsync()
    .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.type === "success") {
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            null,
            response.authentication.accessToken
         );
         await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
        }
   })
   .catch((error) => setError(error))
   .finally(() => setLoading(false));
};
```

Function called on Button click in Login.js

```
 <Pressable
      style={{ backgroundColor: myColors.primary, padding: 20 }}
      onPress={SignInWithGoogle}
  >
    <Text>Login</Text>
  </Pressable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like so:

```
<Pressable
      style={{ backgroundColor: myColors.primary, padding: 20 }}
      onPress={() => SignInWithGoogle}
  >
    <Text>Login</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: doesn't work like this as well.

Comment: I tried your code in a expo snack and it registers the click as intended, perhaps your problem is with the async flow you have implemented.